# Streamlined deploy of SSDT Database Project to localdb

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, database-project

If you have a SSDT Database project in VS 2015 set as the startup project, it performs both a build and deploy when you hit F5

`========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========`

This is different than "Publish..." command, because it does not take you through the publish dialog.  It just automatically deploys to the localdb instance(pointed to via the project's Debug config.

I often need to deploy the database to localdb so that I can run code generation tools against it, rather than running the entire solution(that has other applications, i.e. I would not want to run via F5).

So what I want to do is determine if there is a project level commend that I can add to my toolbar that does this automatic no-dialog deploy to localdb, other than F5's Start Debug command.  I am looking through the Add Command dialog(right click toolbar->Customize), and also looked through the SSDT.* commands from the Keyboard customize in options.

Does anyone know if there is a command just for a Database project Build+Deploy or Deploy, that does it automatically?  (Again the "Publish..." command is not what I'm looking for because it doesn't automatically deploy as above)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have played around with different ways to do this, my two approaches I sway between are:

1. Have a powershell script to call sqlpackage.exe to deploy the dacpac. Build the project as normal (ctrl+shift + b) then alt tab to powershell and run the last command (the deploy script)
2. Use StudioShell (https://studioshell.codeplex.com/) to create a visual studio command to do the build then deploy which you can then map

(2) is closer to what you want but I personally prefer (1) as it is much simpler. The benefits for me for using (1) are:

- The script is the same one I use in CI, QA, Prod etc to deploy the dacpac so it means I test it lots (and lots)
- I see any errors and warnings easily and can keep an eye on when objects are being re-deployed over and over so I can fix the issue rather than not noticing and the deploy times getting longer and longer

I see similar questions like this quite a lot so I thought I would write up my thoughts properly on this: https://the.agilesql.club/blog/Ed-Elliott/Visual-Studio-SSDT-Publish-My-Personal-Best-Practices

Whatever you do (this or something else) follow up with your experiences, I (at least!) would find it interesting!

ed

Comment: Did not know about sqlpackage.exe, thanks.  I was able to put this in a post build event so it'd happen on build.  Not sure it is the right solution since it essentially is hardcoded for debug Build, but you could probably combine this with profiles to get something more flexible for different build(see link).  I don't really want it to automatically deploy anywhere other than localdb in my case, and other deployments are explicit using schema compare+scripting to file. http://www.benday.com/2012/12/18/deploy-a-sql-server-database-projects-dacpac-with-sqlpackage-exe/

Answer (score 1):

I found two alternatives:

1. Right-click the solution, select "Startup Project", "Multiple startup projects", and make the database project one of them.
2. Right-click the solution, select "Project Dependencies", and make the database project a dependency on one of the other projects that will be built.